# Customizing Zurb Foundation 4 Elements

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

Using Foundation 4 buttons allows you to customize design using the mixins.
This is the same for most elements.

However, there are many settings that the mixins don't expose to customization, e.g.:
Font color
Hover effect
Border color

These are all calculated based on the button background color. 
The button is just an example, but I have the same issue with all other elements.

Is there a recommended way to customize parts which are not exposed by the mixin?
I don't want to go into the source and change the actual mixin definition.
If my design spec is very different from Foundation defaults, would it be better to not use Foundation?

Answer (score 1):

Almost every setting can be customized using SASS variables.  The most common ones are accessible in [_variables.scss](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/_variables.scss), but you can overwrite any of the other variables used in the actual component SCSS files.

For values that don't already have variables, you can override the styles using CSS and include the overrides in a wrapper mixin.  Ex:

```
@mixin my-button-style($bg:$primary-color, $radius:false, $disabled:false) {
  @include button-style($bg, $radius, $disabled);

  /* CSS overrides go here */
  border-color: pink; /* etc */

}
```